# How do I implement these super class methods?

Tags: java, methods, superclass

What I'm supposed to do:
write a java program to show the inheritance concept with an Employee being the super class and the Manager being the sub-class. Follow the following class structure: -  Employee class

Variables:

1. Employee Number
2. Employee Name
3. Employee Salary

Constructor – Use this to initialize all the variables above Functions

```
Display() – This displays all the 3 variable values.
setSalary() – This sets the salary variable.
getSalary() – This gets the salary variable.
```

Heres what I have so far

```
public class Employee {
    private int employeeNumber;
    private String employeeName;
    private double employeeSalary;

    public Employee(int employeeNumber, String employeeName, double employeeSalary) {
    this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
    this.employeeSalary = employeeSalary;
    }
}
```

My question is how do I implement those three methods?
Are they just standard getters and setters?
I'm not familiar with the display function, if anyone can help with that
thanks!

Comment: create one more class called `Manager extends Employee` because every manager is employ but every employe is not manager. Create only those methods in Employe which are common between a peon for example and between manager.

Comment: Functions which are only for manager , create those functions in manager class.

Comment: Would this display function be correct @LuaiGhunim                                              public void display()
     {
        System.out.println(employeeSalary + employeeName +employeeNumber);
);
     }

Comment: i answered below and added few extra getters and setter btw you should remember when we say `new` it means we create a new object

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

You are really close. You need to create the manager Class and extend the Employee Class. But first let's add the described method for setting the salary and displaying all the fields!

**Employee Class:** The display() method concatenates the fields together separating them by line.

```
public class Employee {

    private int employeeNumber;
    private String employeeName;
    private double employeeSalary;

    public Employee(int employeeNumber, String employeeName, double employeeSalary){
        this.employeeNumber=employeeNumber;
        this.employeeName=employeeName;
        this.employeeSalary=employeeSalary;
    }


    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Employee Number: "+ employeeNumber +"\n"
                + "Employee Name: " + employeeName + "\n" 
                + "Employee Salary: "  + employeeSalary);
    }

    public double getEmployeeSalary() {
        return employeeSalary;
    }

    public void setEmployeeSalary(double employeeSalary) {
        this.employeeSalary = employeeSalary;
    }

}
```

**Manager Class:** From general knowledge I would assume that a Manager could have multiple employees also. 
So in this class you'd have specific methods for the Manager, such as adding a new Employee, or displaying or the Employees who work for a given Manager.

```
public class Manager extends Employee {


    List<Employee> subordinates;
    public Manager(int employeeNumber, String employeeName, double employeeSalary) {
        super(employeeNumber, employeeName, employeeSalary);
        subordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    public void displayEmployees(){
        for(Employee employee: subordinates){
            employee.display();

            // just print an empty line - so its prettier
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void addNewEmployee(Employee employee){
        subordinates.add(employee);
    }

    public List<Employee> getSubordinates() {
        return subordinates;
    }

    public void setSubordinates(List<Employee> subordinates) {
        this.subordinates = subordinates;
    }
}
```

**Testing:** note that a Manager inherits all the methods of the Employee class, which is why within the Manager class there was no need to override the methods, but of course that can be done to add new functionality.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Manager manager = new Manager(11111, "Elon Musk", 42344);
        manager.display();


        // lets make some employees who work for the above manager

        Employee employeeOne = new Employee(324, "Bob Den", 3522);
        Employee employeeTwo = new Employee(44, "Tim Pipe", 4234 );
        Employee employeeThree = new Employee(42, "Asif Blar", 4321);

        // lets add the new employees to the managers list of employees ( this can further be refactored )

        manager.addNewEmployee(employeeOne);
        manager.addNewEmployee(employeeTwo);
        manager.addNewEmployee(employeeThree);

        // lets display all the employees who work for the manager
        manager.displayEmployees();


        // lets give the manager a 10 % raise
        double employeeSalary = manager.getEmployeeSalary();
        manager.setEmployeeSalary(employeeSalary +(employeeSalary /10));

        // lets print out the managers hefty new salary
        manager.display();

    }
}
```

Comment: Constructor of Employee in Manager? Why is that?

Comment: He will get an error and this is not the proper way to create a manager since a manager can have more attributes or few different attributes.

Comment: With one constructor you can only create Employe not a manager because Manager can have extra attributes which you can give while creating a manager. In simple every Manager is an employe but every employe is not a manager.

Comment: Ok i ask you to create a peon class which takes two extra attributes and make it a subclass of Employee and you need to make difference between two different object.

Comment: For Peone  you just create `Employee peon= new Employe(...)` and for Manager you create `Employe manager = new Employe(..) ` does not make  sense at all.

Comment: I commented before you editted your answer, go back and  check what was written before in editted sessions.

Comment: I answered your questions :)

Comment: Editted your question and then tried to argue, instead of that you should have editted it and then simply had not asked me what is wrong.

Comment: Nope, This is not a compiler error  `Employe manager = new Employe(..)`. I got nothing wrong in my answer , 3 functions are overriden that does not make a code wrong but if you look in his question his fields are declared private.

Comment: You should avoid serial down-voting on my other questions.

Comment: I think i answerd why i used overriding ,that's because your getter returns a pointer to your object and in that case you can manipulate things of an objects by only getter. Overriding , you can add clone or copy value to new variable .

Comment: You can do this in Employee also but that constraint is at very higher level and then if other subclass wants to manipulate things, then it can't btw i remove my downvote ,

Comment: What is wrong. you mean you can't change things with getter?

Comment: Delete your comments, they are just noise @LuaiGhunim